`TypeError: metaclass conflict` for a Subclass of `type`
I made an abstract base class MyABC, whose metaclass is, of coarse, abc.ABCMeta. Then, I wanted to make a class SubType, whose instances are a subclass of MyABC. Since the instance of it is a class, I thought it would be good to make it as a subclass of type. That is,

SubType is a subclass of type.
The instance of SubType is a subclass of MyABC.

The following is the code structure I wrote:
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyABC(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_abstract_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def some_mixin_method(self):
        print('some_mixin_method()')
        self.some_abstract_method()

class SubType(type):
    _types = dict()

    def __new__(cls, string):
        if string in cls._types:
            # subclass of MyABC with given string has already been made
            self = cls._types[string]
        else:
            # subclass of MyABC with given string has not been made
            name = f'Class_{string}'
            bases = (MyABC,)
            dict_ = {
                'string': string,
                'some_abstract_method': cls._some_abstract_method
                }
            # type(name, bases, dict) => new type instance (class)
            self = super(SubType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)
            cls._types[string] = self

        return self

    @staticmethod
    def _some_abstract_method(self):
        print('some_abstract_method()')
        print(f'string: {self.string}')

Class_Foo = SubType('Foo')

and the result is like below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    Class_Foo = SubType('Foo')
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 17, in __new__
    self = super(SubType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Since Class_Foo is not a subclass, but an instance of SubType, I don't think this is the case of metaclass conflict, but the interpreter thinks it is. Does anyone here who can describe what is wrong and how to fix it?

You are confusing things a bit there, but TL;DR: what you need to work around this error is that your metaclass is also derived from ABCMeta -
There are other answers around, just instructing people to create a third metaclass that would inherit from both ABCMeta and the other metaclass of interest. (It is needed, for example, for Python-Qt code that will use any abstract class).
However, in this case, since you are creating your own custom metaclass, all you need is that it inherits from ABCMeta, instead of directly from type.
In other words, just change this line:
class SubType(type):

to
class SubType(ABCMeta):

and your code should just work as is.
As for the other details: usually when we are writing metaclasses, it is more clear if we change the usual cls and self parameter names to mcls (or metacls, or any other name that makes it easy to see we are dealing with the metaclass), and self to cls: since the instance is always a class. But that is actually more a matter of style than a hard convention.
